# RAM upgrade – iMac Mid 2011

Tags: imac, memory

I’ve got an iMac Mid 2011 with 4GB RAM preinstalled (2 x 2GB) and want to upgrade to 12GB.
Is it ok to add a single 8GB RAM or is it better to add 2 x 4GB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single DIMMs might not be supported, depending on the model of iMac you have. According to this [Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1423):

> **Additional notes** i5 and i7 Quad Core iMac computers come with both top memory slots populated. These computers will not start up if only
>   a single DIMM is installed in any bottom slot; these computers should
>   operate normally with a single DIMM installed in any top slot. Core
>   Duo iMac computers should operate normally with a single DIMM
>   installed in any slot, top or bottom. ("Top" and "bottom" slots refer
>   to the orientation of the slots in the pictures below. "Top" refers to
>   the slots closest to the display; "bottom" refers to the slots closest
>   to the stand)

As a side note, 8GB DIMMS are not officially supported - only 2 or 4 GB SO-DIMMs. However, according to this [OWC page](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/memory/iMac/2011/DDR3_21.5_27), 8GB DIMMs do work (4 x 8GB).